# Best RESTful route design for CSV uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

What's the best practice for RESTful route design when allowing users the option either to fill out a form at `/new` or else upload a `csv file` containing data for multiple objects?

For simplicity of my controller actions I'd rather add two new routes such as `get :upload` and `post :create_multiple`, for uploading a CSV file containing data for multiple entity objects.

This is a simple enough situation but I'm curious if anyone has given it enough thought to decide on an intelligent pattern that yields simple and easily tested controller actions?

Answer (score 0):

**RESTful**

I think you need to look beyond `CSV` and consider the resourceful structure of how the system will work - if you treat the `CSV` file as, say, a `Paperclip` attachment, the process for setting up the required routes etc is still the same -

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller, path_names: {new: "upload"} do
    collection do
        post :create_multiple
    end
end
```

This will give you the following controller setup:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_record, except: [:index, :new, :create]
    def new
       @model = Model.new
    end

    def create
       @model = Model.new(model_params)
       @model.save
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        @model.update(model_params)
    end

    def index
        @models = Model.all
    end

    def destroy
       @model.destroy
    end

    def show
    end

    def create_multiple
    end 

    private

    def models_params
        parmas.require(:model).permit(:params, :for, :object)
    end

    def set_record
        @model = Model.find parmas[:id]
    end
end
```

If you want to manipulate the CSV file in the backend, you'll be able to do this in the model - either by using an `instance` / `class` method, or using some other dependency

Comment: I like the thinking here, but it makes me want to clarify... that the CSV data represents not something that would be attached to an object but rather a list of objects.  Although I should say, I finally decided that getting this done was better than philosophizing over it, since it's likely not an issue that we must confront all the time.